# Creating a local bare repo to act as remote

Tags: git

I'm somewhat familiar with git when using it from an online hosting site like GitHub or BitBucket but now trying to recreate the structure entirely local. I am trying to create the structure locally with the following:

1. On a network drive I have a folder 'codeRepo' which I want to contain the remote, bare repositories that code will be pulled from.
2. The remote bare 'codeRepo', is cloned to a folder 'deployedAuto', and is run with task scheduler. This is the 'local' code that I don't want to be changed without approved commits/merges. In order to update this clone, it will be pulled from the remote, and branches will need to be merged.
3. There is then the user-based clones in individuals' folders: 'programmerA', 'programmerB', etc. If changes to the 'deployedAuto' code are required, they are made by each programmer in their respective local clone. These edits are then pushed to the bare remote, reviewed, and merged once confirmed to work. Finally, the 'deployedAuto' clone will pull from the bare, 'codeRepo', and then have the most recent functioning code.

My first question is: am I correctly conceptualizing the structure to replicate a web-hosted remote repo on an entirely local network?

My second question is: Am I doing this correctly below:

1. Create a new folder 'codeRepo.git':

```
cd c:\path\to\local\remote\codeRepo.git
git init --bare .
```

2. Clone this empty, bare repo to the local folder 'deployedAuto'

```
cd c:\path\to\deployedAuto
git clone c:\path\to\local\remote\codeRepo.git
```

3. Add all folders/files within the newly cloned repo
   `git add .`
4. Push to the remote (local) server
   `git push`
5. Now the local programmers can clone the bare repo. Create a new branch to make edits, push the branch to the bare repo. To test the newly created branch, the 'deployedAuto' will pull the bare repo, test changes and merge branches as needed.

Have I approached, and implemented this correctly? Will this approach cause any issues with version control in the future?

Am I able to manage the local remote repo with something like VS Code, or the GUI Git application? For example, can I delete/merge branches pushed to the remote using VS Code?

Comment: Looks fine. Is there a problem?

Comment: Btw you might want to read https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows

Comment: It's generally unwise to store Git repositories in *shared* folders. (A network folder might be shared or private.) It's also often a lot slower to use a network folder than a local drive. Other than that and another minor nit, this seems fine. (The minor nit is: `git add` never adds any *folder*, it only adds *files*. The files may have path names like `path/to/file.ext`. Note that Git internally stores them with *forward* slashes, even though Windows uses backslash. Git does the conversions back and forth as needed.)

Comment: @torek My guess would be storing the remote in a shared folder runs the risk of people accidentally making changes to the bare repo? Any other downsides? With regards to `git add`, is there an alternative?

Comment: Right - anything shared could potentially be modified by someone, perhaps more than one "someone" at a time. It's that last—competing modifications—that leads to trouble. The nit about `git add` is that Git never stores any folders at all, it only stores files. The checkout process, which extracts the stored files from a commit, will *create* OS-level folders as required, but Git did not store them, it just stored files with names that required OS-level folders.